# If $\sum_ix^i\partial_if=0$, then $f$ is constant?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, differential

Let $f$ be a real-valued function defined on a neighborhood $D$ of $0\in\mathbb R^n$ - is it true that $\sum_ix^i\partial_if=0$ implies that $f$ is constant? Intuitively, I'd say yes:

Consider the radial vector field $R(x):=x$, then $\sum_i x^i\partial_if=\mathrm df(R)$ and we get that $f$ is constant on each ray emanating from the origin. Because of continuity, $f$ should be constant everywhere.

Is my reasoning correct? What properties does $D$ need to have such that everything works out? (My guess would be that $D$ needs to be star-shaped w.r.t. the origin.)

Motivation: As far as I understand, this is used in the proof of Lemma $4.13$ of [Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators](https://link.springer.com/book/9783540200628).

Comment: In my opinion $\Sigma_{i}x^i\partial_i f = 0$ define a [non-linear partial differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_partial_differential_equation), which could have a trivial solution $f=0$, but also many other solutions $f\neq 0$ in the domain near the origin.

Comment: @Joako How is this nonlinear?

Comment: $f^{'}(x)=0$ only implies $f$ is locally constant. If $f$ is locally constant on each ray and D is star-shaped, then $f$ is constant on each ray.  Then it must be identically equal to $f(0)$. I think star-shaped is a good condition and I can't come up with any weaker condition.

Comment: Maybe I have misinterpreted the equation, but don't it leads in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to something like $x\ f_x+y^2\ f_y+z^3\ f_z = 0$?

Comment: @Joako Yes, you misinterpreted the equation:$$(x^1,x^2,x^3)=(x,y,z)$$

Comment: so It is $xf_x+yf_y+zf_z=0$? that is still nonlinear PDF... linear PDFs are like $f_{xx}-f_{yy}+f_y=0$ as example (also, of notation I am using)

Comment: @Joako "So it is...?" - Exactly. What do you mean by linear? The differential operator$$f\mapsto\sum_ix^i\partial_if$$is $\mathbb R$-linear, isn't it?

Comment: @Koobe So you agree with my reasoning?

Comment: @Filippo Yes...